# curl `effective_url`not getting the last effective url

Tags: php, curl

I need to get the last effective URL with curl for this website:
http://www.wechat.com/en/
When I use curl's `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);`I get `http://www.wechat.com/`, but if you visit the site you can see the URL changes by adding /en/ on the end.

Code:

```
 $url = 'http://www.wechat.com';
 $curl = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 $ip = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP);
 $last_effective_url = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
 curl_close($curl);

 echo $last_effective_url;
```

I'm going out of my mind here. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that there is no HTTP redirect code to the `/en/` url that CURL can interprete. CURL sees a HTTP200 and stops there.

Instead, the page is refreshed by Javascript in the browser that cannot be interpreted by CURL.

So the effective URL for CURL is 'http://www.wechat.com', and that is correct behaviour.

Look at the source of the page http://www.wechat.com/ (view-source:http://www.wechat.com/index.html in the browser) to see the javascript in action:

```
 <script>
        (function () {
            Array.prototype.contain = function (f) {
                var e = this.length;
                while (e--) {
                    if (this[e] === f) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            };
            var c = ["en", "zh", "pt", "th", "vi", "id", "es", "ru", "ar", "he", "pl", "hi", "ja", "it", "ko", "ms", "tr"], a = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || 'en', a = a.replace(/-\w+/, ""), d = location.pathname.match(/\/(\w+)\/(\w*)/i), b = c.contain(a) ? a : "en", b = b == "zh" ? "zh_TW" : b;
            if (location.pathname == "/index.html" || location.pathname == "/" || location.pathname == "/cgi-bin/readtemplate") {
                location.href = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/" + b + "/";
                return
            }
            if (d && d[1]) {
                return
            }
            location.href = location.href.replace(/\w+\/(\w+)\//i, function (e, f) {
                return e.replace(f, b)
            })
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: ah I see thanks for pointing it out. I still need to get it though, but it looks like curl's a dead end.